# Select the first element by a specific set of values of the same attribute

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need a CSS selector that returns me the first element (or all of them in the correct order) by a specific set of values of the same attribute.

**A bad example, but you'll get the idea:**

```
input[type=text][type=email][type=number]:first
```

**From this example HTML:**

```
<input type="date" />
<input type="email" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="password" />
```

**The selector must select** `<input type="email" />` **or**

```
<input type="email" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="password" />
```

It's ok to return all of them. But they must be in the original order. For example:

```
input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=number]
```

Is not suitable as it selects elements in the wrong order. First all `type=text`, then `type=email` etc.

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me, because the “order” in which different elements are selected does not make any difference from CSS’ view.

Comment: It's like this. I need only 1 input, the first. When it's not possible to return 1, the whole set may be returned. Then I can use JS to pick the first. That's when the order does matter. The selector is called from the JS in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe I asked for a CSS selctor with a purpose. That purpose is replacing/removing the working JS code which selects all inputs, returns and puts them into working memory, picks first, performs checks etc etc. Performance, bug risks, code maintainability are important over here.

Comment: Well if your question is about improving some JS code, then you should show that code – and not ask in a way that does not in any way hint at what the actual problem you are trying to solve is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS you cannot get the first element inside a container based on a set of attributes, you can only do this with element types using nth-of-type. You can, however, set something like a required order and then pick in JS the first result available using the plus selector: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#selectors

Comment: Thank you. This concludes that it cannot be done I guess, at least with CSS3. I can accept this as an answer. BTW please remove your supplied CSS to prevent confusion for others. As it does totally something else. Your solution selects all `input[type="text"]` elements that are placed immediately after `input[type="email"]` elements, only when those are placed immediately after `input[type="date"]` elements. What I asked for is to select the first of any of the specified types, regardless of their order in DOM. Thanks for the effort though!

Answer (score 0):

There is no first-match selector in CSS like jQuery's `:first`, so you won't be able to do this using pure CSS.

As mentioned in the comments, selectors themselves do not have a notion of order. You have a selector, and then you have all the elements in the DOM that would match that selector. In a comma-separated list of selectors, the ordering does not matter, except in CSS where the most specific of these selectors takes precedence for the purposes of cascade resolution (e.g. for an element that matches both selectors in `input, input[type=email]`, the latter is considered in style resolution).

Using JavaScript, however, you can use `document.querySelector()` to pick out the first match, as it does have a notion of order:

```
document.querySelector('input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=number]')
```

Note again that ordering does not matter in a selector list; in this case, it depends on the order of your elements in the DOM. In your example, assuming those are the only `input` elements of their kind in the entire DOM, or you have an appropriate scope from which to match elements, `document.querySelector()` will always match the `input[type=email]` first, even though it's specified after `input[type=text]` in the selector list, simply because it comes first in the DOM.

Comment: Well according to my tests in Mootools framework. The performance friendly method, that selects the first element only: `getElement('input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=number]')` will always return the item of type that stands first in the selector, independent of the DOM order. It is only when I retrieve all elements at once using: `getElements('input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=number]')` is when the order in the selector list doesn't matter.

Comment: @Alph Dev: Well that's just weird, and certainly not the same behavior as the standard. You might be able to work around that behavior by using the standard API instead of Mootools' `getElement()` to select your element.